# Converting cstruct to python string

Tags: types, cython

Here's a summary of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Convert an opaque cstruct to a python Array
2. Pickle the Array

I'm having issues with persuading cython to let me convert C object into a python object.

Here's a simplified version of the code that's giving me headaches. 
This is in file myothermodule.pyx

```
cdef char* struct_to_string(structtype ctarg):
    cdef:
        bspmat *bsptarg
        list arrays = []
        np.ndarray[np.float64_t, ndim=2] arr
        char * string_data

    for i in range(ctarg.numlevel):
         bsptarg = ctarg.level[i]
         arr = bspmat_to_array(bsptarg) #this works fine in other contexts
         arrays.append(arr)

    cdef bytes pystr = cPickle.dumps(arrays, protocol=2) #fastest protocol
    string_data = <char *> pystr

    return string_data
```

This code is in my middle.pyx:

```
cdef push_data(mycythonstruct pv):
    cdef:
        cdef char * strdata
        cdef myothermodule.structtype *ctarg
    ctarg = pv.another_cython_struct
    strdata = myothermodule.struct_to_string( ctarg )
```

This is the type of error that results when trying to compile:

```
middle.pyx:232:45: Cannot convert 'structtype *' to Python object

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------

    [...]

    ctarg = pv.another_cython_struct
    strdata = myothermodule.struct_to_string( ctarg )
                                    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

middle.pyx:232:37: Obtaining 'char *' from temporary Python value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 21, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize(extensions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 785, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args[1:])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/Cython-0.20.1-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 902, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: middle.pyx
```

Any clues as to how to persuade this to work would be appreciated!

Comment: Your first error has to to do with the difference between `structtype` and a `structtype*`. You might be able to solve it by changing the definition of `cdef char* struct_to_string(structtype* ctarg)` (but it's difficult to be certain since you haven't provided the definition of `structtype`)

Comment: (Actually, I think that probably isn't what's causing your _first_ error message, but it definitely is a problem)

Comment: Do you have *myothermodule.pxd* that has definitions of `structtype` and `struct_to_string`, and then `cimport myothermodule` in *middle.pyx*? And should `myothermodule.struct_to_string( ctarg )` be `myothermodule.struct_to_string( ctarg[0] )` i.e. not a pointer?